# Jacobian composite function claims

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

So I'm working with Jacobimatrices. However, the lecture notes claim two results which I cannot figure out since there are no explanation of it.

So let $\textbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a function given below $$\textbf{F}(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$$
where we know that $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We define the Jacobimatrix as follows,
$$D\textbf{F}(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_1(x,y) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_1(x,y)\\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_2(x,y) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_2(x,y)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Further, we define $c:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as follows
$$\textbf{c}(t)=(c_1(t),c_2(t))$$
Now here is the first claim:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{F}(\textbf{c}(t))=D\textbf{F}(\textbf{c}(t))\textbf{c}'(t)$$

---

Before the second claim, we first define $\textbf{G}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a function given below $$\textbf{G}(x,y)=(g_1(x,y),g_2(x,y))$$ Then we say $\textbf{H}(x,y)=\textbf{F}(\textbf{G}(x,y))$

The second claim are as follows:
$$D\textbf{H}(x,y)=D\textbf{F}(\textbf{G}(x,y))D\textbf{G}(x,y)$$

I cannot see how this could be true. Can anyone explain these two claims for me? Thanks in advance

Comment: chain rule ....

Comment: Yea I see that I shall use chain rule, but the problem is to set the equations up. I cannot figure out how to write F(c(t)). Yet I know this might be very simple but in the end my calculations messed up.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The claims are exactly the chain rule... Maybe your problem is that your only know the chain rule for functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (?)